# React component doesn't re-render on updating state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I think u know better solution for this:
I have file with array of objects with my cats:

```
var categories = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name" : "Faktury",
    "selected" : false
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name" : "Telefony",
    "selected" : false
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name" : "Komputery",
    "selected" : false
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "name" : "Rachunkowośc",
    "selected" : false
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "name" : "Finanse",
    "selected" : false
  }
];
```

and i have:

```
<ul className="category">
  {this.state.categories.map((item,index) =>
    <li onClick={()=>this.filterCategory(item,index)} key={item.id} className={item.selected? 'active' : ''}>{item.name}</li>
  )}
</ul>
```

and my filterCategory:

```
filterCategory(item,index) {
  this.state.categories[index].selected = !this.state.categories[index].selected;
  this.forceUpdate();
}
```

Do u know how i can make it without `forceUpdate()` ?  I have read on stack i should avoid use `this.forceUpdate()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `setState` automatically triggers a rerender, so instead of directly mutating the state use `setState` to update the state.

```
filterCategory(item,index){
   var categories = [...this.state.categories];
   categories[index].selected = !categories[index].selected;
   this.setState({categories})
}
```

According to the DOCS:

> NEVER mutate this.state directly, as calling setState() afterwards may
>   replace the mutation you made. Treat this.state as if it were
>   immutable.

Comment: i think spread operator doesn't do a deep copy it will still have the reference of all the objects and affect the state values also, run this code: `let obj = [{a:1}, {a:2}];

let k = [...obj];

k[0].a = 10;

console.log(k, obj);` [**check this LINK**](http://www.bambielli.com/til/2017-01-29-spread-operator-deep-copy/) correct me if i am missing something :)

Comment: @MayankShukla You are infact right. Thats mentioned in Spread operator docs as well: Note: Spread syntax effectively goes one level deep while copying an array. Therefore, it may be unsuitable for copying multidimensional arrays as the following example shows

Comment: @MayankShukla, we can do a deep cloning with spread syntax or Object.assign but that will complicate the code. I haven't faced any problems with the above approach, so I just use it

Comment: @PawełBaca consider accepting the answer if it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

[Do Not Modify State Directly](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly)

Use setState method for state changes.