# How to loop through an array of objects and get specific key values in React?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I want to use either `forEach` or `map` to loop through an array that has multiple objects in it. These objects have a key `price` and a value for it. I'm was trying to use `forEach` but I can't get it to work. This is my component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {addCart} from './Shop'; 
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

export class Cart extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {items: this.props.cart,cart: [],total: 0};
    }

    ...

    countTotal() {
        this.state.cart.forEach((item, index) => {
            console.log(this.state.items);
            this.state.total = this.state.total + this.state.items.price;
            console.log(this.state.total);
        })
    }

    ...

    render() {
        return(
            <div className= "Webcart" id="Webcart">
            </div>
        );
    }
}

...
```

In `countTotal`, `console.log(this.state.items)` outputs various objects that each look like

```
item:"Hoodie"
price:25
size:"large"
```

How can I loop through each object and get the `price` value so I can add it up in my function?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any other way to avoid React forceUpdate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45187529/is-there-any-other-way-to-avoid-react-forceupdate)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer how to loop through an array, you can use a simple `for` loop in javascript as you would in a language like C;

```
let total = 0;
for(let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    total += item[i].price
}
```

React following a functional approach, we prefer `map` and `reduce` as it makes your code more declarative. Hence,

```
const total = items.reduce((acc, item) => {
  return acc + item.price;
}, 0)
```

Your code would look like this then,

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';


export class Cart extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {items: props.cart,cart: [],total: 0};
  }


  countTotal() {
    return this.state.items.reduce((acc, item) => {
      return acc + item.price;
    }, 0)
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div className= "Webcart" id="Webcart">
        { this.countTotal() }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Cart cart={
              [
                {
                  item:"Hoodie",
                  price:25,
                  size:"large"
                },
                {
                  item:"Gloves",
                  price: 12,
                  size:"large"
                },
                {
                  item:"boots",
                  price:30,
                  size:"large"
                },
              ]
            } />
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

***Note
There is not `setState` used. `total`  is derived data. Derived data must not reside in state.***

Yet if for some reason you still need it,  `countTotal` would look like this,

```
countTotal() {
   this.setState(state => {
     return {
        total: state.items.reduce((acc, item) => {
          return acc + item.price;
        }, 0)
     };
   });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should not assign directly to state, you should use `setState` instead. `forEach` is fine, but I would recommend you skip `forEach` and `map` and use `reduce`, pulling only the price key out of the object:

```
countTotal() {
   this.setState({
      total: this.state.cart.reduce((total, { price }) => total + price, 0)
   });
}
```

Comment: If I do `console.log(this.state.total)` after `this.setState() {` I get 0..

Comment: setState is asynchronous, your console log will fire before it is done. Put the console log in the render method or render the total

Comment: I would suggest using the callback form of `setState` as you are accessing `this.state` to calculate the new state: `this.setState(prevState => ({ total: prevState.cart.reduce((total, {price}) => total + price)});`

Comment: Even placing it in my render emthod gives me 0 @RobM.

Comment: I haven't been able to get this to work, at least in my console log. I'm trying to render the `total` value in a div but I have problems with because using `{this.state.total}` returns an error about rendering multiple child elements.. Any help with this?@RobM.

Comment: I just updated my answer to include the starting value of `0` in the reduce, please try with the updated code

Comment: I'm trying `render() {
  console.log(this.state.total);
  return(`

Comment: Sounds like one of your `price` values is not a number, if that is the case you need to adjust the code to filter out non-numeric values before you `reduce`

Comment: @RobM. Object form of `setState` is not recommended after React 16

Comment: @ManasJayanth interesting, would you mind sharing a link to the React documentation that states this? I couldn't find it on https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html

Comment: @RobM. Its not official. React 16 doesn't have async rendering on. When it does, object form of setState can lead to issues.

You can checkout Lin Clark's talk about Fiber where she mentions it. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZCuYPiUIONs.

(Travelling right now. Will post the exact seconds of the video later)

Comment: Thanks much, @ManasJayanth - will watch that this afternoon :)

Comment: I highly recommend it :)